# Passing Login info into Force CLI

Tags: oauth2, urlhacking, force-cli

Is it possible to hack the Force CLI to pass login info in from the command line?

Looking at the [code here](https://github.com/heroku/force/blob/master/force.go#L183), you can see that its using oauth2 to get a token.

Maybe there is a URL hack to pass the Username/Password into the oAuth URL?  Of course you would still have to grant permissions the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it would be possible with the current pre-compiled binaries that are available for download; however, the latest and greatest source code has the ability to do what you want without any sort of hacking.

Take a look at the [login.go](https://github.com/heroku/force/blob/master/login.go) file usage. There are login options that take a user name and password that use SOAP behind the scenes to log in:

> `force login un pw      # log in using SOAP`
>   
>   `force login test un pw # log in using SOAP to sandbox org`

You can issue the command.

```
$ force login un pw
```

Make sure that you include the security token on the end of the password if you are outside of your trusted/whitelisted IP ranges.

I had to compile from source as [documented in the Hacking section](https://github.com/heroku/force) (copied at the end of this answer for reference), since there are not precompiled binaries.  Here is what I had to do on my Windows machine.

- [Install the Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/doc/install)
- [Install Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download) and add Mercurial to my PATH.
- I already had git, so I did not need to install that.
- I also have cygwin, but that isn't 100% necessary.

**The Hacking directions**

```
# set these environment variables in your startup scripts
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"

# download the source and all dependencies
$ go get -u github.com/heroku/force
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/heroku/force

# to compile and test modifications
$ go get .
$ force
```

Following the [Hacking directions](https://github.com/heroku/force) results in a force executable file (force.exe) being created in the ~/go/bin directory.  You can then use that executable.

Once I did that I was able to sucessfully login using the command:

```
force login myusername@mydomain.com mypasswordMySecurityToken
```

Comment: great answer.  I pretty much just discovered the exact same thing and was coming here to answer my own question.  You did a way better job than I would have though

Comment: This inspired me to document how to start off hacking the CLI in [this post](http://peterknolle.com/hacking-the-force-com-cli/).